# How do I convert this SQL inner join query into LINQ syntax?

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, sql-to-linq-conversion

I'm not that familiar with LINQ. I need this query converted into a LINQ statement for use inside my C# project.

Thanks

```
SELECT Galleries.GalleryTitle, Media.*
FROM Galleries 
INNER JOIN Media ON Galleries.GalleryID = Media.GalleryID
WHERE (Galleries.GalleryID = 100)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var query = from g in db.Galleries
            join m in db.Media on g.GalleryID equals m.GalleryID into gm
            where g.GalleryID == 100
            select new { g.GalleryTitle, Media = gm };
```

Property `Media` will contain list of joined media entities. Also if you have navigation property defined in Gallery entity, then:

```
var gallery = db.Galleries.Include("Media")
                .FirstOrDefault(g => g.GalleryID == 100);
```